# $x^2+3x+b=0$ has an integer solution (mod $17$) for which $b\lt 17$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all non-negative integers $b<17$ such that the equation $x^2+3x+b=0$ has an integer solution (mod $17$).

I know this is probably obvious. But I have no idea what to search for to find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $17$ is prime, we can invert any $1,\ldots,16$. Then $$x^2+3x=(x+3/2)^2-9/4$$

and in fact $2\cdot 8=16=-1$ so $2^{-1}=-8=9$, and $4^{-1}=9\cdot 9=81=13$. That is, $x^2+3x=(x+10)^2-13$ so you want $(x+10)^2=13-b$. That is, you want $13-b$ to be a quadratic residue modulo $17$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If the equation has an integer solution mod $17$, then it factors, say as $(x+r)(x+s)$. Expand that, set the two equal, and see what you can determine about $r$ and $s$.

Answer (score 0):

The standard methods for solving quadratic equations works modulo any odd prime number just as well as they do with real numbers. Work through completing the square if you're uncomfortable just assuming the quadratic formula is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+3x+b\equiv 0\pmod{17}\\4x^2+12x+4b\equiv 0\pmod{17}\\(2x+3)^2\equiv 3^2-4b\pmod{17}\\(2x+3)^2\equiv9-4b\pmod{17}$$
So we have that $9-4b$ must be a square $\pmod{17}$ you can replace the $b$ with numbers from 0 to 16 and use the Euler's criterion to see if $9-4b$ is sqaure modulo 17

Answer (score 0):

Modulo $17$, $2^{-1} = 9$, so we can write 
$$
x^2 + 3x + b = (x + 10)^2 + (b-100) =  (x + 10)^2 + (b+2) \text{ (mod } 17).
$$

Now we then have

$$
(x + 10)^2 + (b+2) = 0\text{ (mod } 17),
$$
which is just 
$$
(x + 10)^2  = -(b+2) \text{ (mod } 17).
$$
So we must have that, modulo 17, $-(b+2)$ is a square. So, as 17 is quite small, we can just check which numbers $b$ give $-(b+2)$ a square modulo 17.